# PID for Julia REPL launched IJulia (Jupyter) notebook

Tags: macos, julia, jupyter-notebook

It's quite convenient to launch an IJulia notebook from the Julia REPL.

It's also nice to free up the REPL by using

```
 julia>notebook(detached=true)
 Process(setenv(/Users/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/bin/jupyter notebook 
 --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=2147483647; 
 dir="/Users/myJulia/"), ProcessRunning)
```

is there a way within Julia to get the PID (process ID?) of the notebook (not the REPL), other than using a shell command like

```
pgrep -if jupyter-notebook
```

this returns the PID, however, i might have multiple notebooks runninng so it would not be obvious which one is which.  since the notebook in this case is detached, it doesn't die even when the kernel is stopped, the notebook closed, and jupyter is logged out form.  i know how to kill a process.  it would just be cleaner if i could get the PID more directly when the notebook is launched.

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate a call to the `getpid()` function, from within a cell in the IJulia notebook.

[image]

Comment: nice thought.  however, getpid() returns the pid of the Julia REPL, not of the notebook which was launched.  the notebook (at least on macos) has a a parent PID of 1. there may be multiple notebooks running, too.  so, perhaps no  direct way to tie the REPL to the notebook just launched.

Comment: So you need the pid from the notebook server?

Comment: the point is to manage the notebook life cycle from within the the REPL.